# Why we define an orthogonal matrix $A$ to be one that $A^TA=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why we define an orthogonal matrix $A$ to be one that $A^TA=I$ rather than just let its rows and columns be orthonormal ?

Note: I ask this because I think that it's more natural to first defined $A$ with orthonormal columns and rows, then prove $A^TA=I$.

Comment: both definitions are equivalent...

Comment: @Surb sorry, I add a clarification, and that's what I want to ask

Comment: On a side note, I personally think that it's more natural either to define a matrix to be orthogonal if the induced linear map preserves the Euclidean norm, or to define it as a matrix which induces a linear map preserving the standard inner product. Third choice would be $A^TA=I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions you mention are actually equivalent and it's quite easy to see why. Let $A = [a_1 \, a_2 \, \cdots \, a_n]$. Observe that the columns of $A$ being orthonormal is equivalent to

$$a_i \cdot a_j = \delta_{ij},$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol. Now consider the matrix product

$$A^TA  = \begin{bmatrix} 
a_1^T \\
a_2^T \\
\vdots \\
a_n^T \end{bmatrix}[a_1 \, a_2 \, \cdots \, a_n],$$

whose $(i,j)$-entry is exactly the scalar product $a_i \cdot a_j$. Do you now see how these definitions are equivalent?

Addendum/edit: Now, this does not exactly answer the question as to *why* we often prefer one definition over the other. The answer is that it is more compact and more useful when doing computation. Definition this kind, i.e. that can be expressed (perhaps more intuitively) in words are defined in a symbolic and more compact way, to ease computation and shorten proofs. Here is another example: We can define a stochastic matrix as a matrix whose entries are non-negative and where the sum over each column is 1. However, this is wordy and seems cumbersome to check. We can equivalently define it as follows:

Let $S = [1 \, 1 \, \cdots \, 1]$ be the $1 \times n$ matrix filled with ones. An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is stochastic if all its entries are non-negative and it satisfies

$$SA = S.$$

This is more compact and versatile than our first definition.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear. I know they are equivalent, but what confused me is that why don't we define its rows and columns to be orthonormal then prove $A^TA=I$. isn't it more natural?

Comment: I have addressed this question now. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, the example is helpful